# How to set success message in Jmeter JSR223 assertion

Tags: groovy, jmeter, assertion

I have a question about assertion message I would like to add in Jmeter JSR223assertion.
I know how to put message if an assertion failed

```
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
```

but if the assertion passed, meaning its all OK is their a way to print a message?

```
AssertionResult.setFailure(false);
```

what to add that I could put a message in Jmeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment you cannot set "assertion success" message, however you can amend parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) message to something custom using the following code in the [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion):

```
prev.setResponseMessage('some custom message')
```

It will result into:

[image: Groovy Set Sampler Message]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks dimity it solved it, can you please advise how to use "setResponseMessage"  for the current sampler, for example if I use JSSR223 sampler for calculation and want to display results in UI,  and can I see the results in Jmeter reports?

Comment: It would be `SampleResult.setResponseMessage('some custom message')`, check out [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, will it display in reports too? if I want to create nightly programs and in morning to see actual results

Comment: Given you configure JMeter to save response message - you will see it in the reports. The relevant property is `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true`, you can [add it to *user.properties* file or pass via -J command-line argument](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

Assertion result doesn't have option to set successful message, but [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as other JSR223 elements have specific variable, you need the `log` variable,

You can print a message to log with error level:

```
log.error("My error...");
```

or log information to log:

```
log.info("My message");
```

also you have `log.debug` or `log.warn` and maybe other function depending on your log implementation (slf4j/log4j...)

Comment: I know but I want it to be displayed in the Sampler results section, like the Assertion results failure message. Is there a way to display message in that part of screen also. in tee Response message can I put something wlse instead of OK that is the default

Comment: See @Ubik answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a success message.

JMeter being a load test tool mainly, we only report details on failed samplers.

You may request an enhancement explaining why you need this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html